# SEO Root Page Didn't Index

Tags: seo

I have a company webpage at "example1.com" and was developing a new webpage at "exemple2.com" (because it was everything already set).

When I finished the page, I updated my "example1.com". So, at this time both "example1.com" and "example2.com" had the exactly same code.

Couple of day later I disabled my "example2.com" site by removing its DNS configs.

But... The root page on google was indexed on "example2.com" and when I removed this domain (and forbidden google to index them at the search console), my root page from "example1.com" didnt get indexed.

So... I have all my pages from "example1.com" indexed (about 6 pages), and my root page isnt indexed... I already try the manual index at search console, but nothing until this moment...

Any tips on how I can solve this? Or this is one of the cases that I just need to wait a month or so?

Thanks!!

Comment: Tips? Just wait. Search engines are not real time or even close. It will simply take time. Weeks or even months depending upon how often Google visits your site. You can of course use Search Console to Fetch and Render to update the new home page, but that is only half of the problem. The remaining half you will have no control over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you may have messed this one up pretty good. By getting your example2.com indexed, Google chose to rank that domain over your example1.com. This was because of duplicate content. You should have been using a rel=canonical header pointing to example1.com to keep it in the SERPs.

Now that you have requested example2.com to be deindexed and removed the DNS, you can't even 301 redirect to example1.com or add the headers in for example2.com.

If you can forward example2.com to example1.com as a 301 redirect I recommend that you consider doing so. And if you do, remove that request to deindex example2.com so that they may crawl it and find example1.com again.

It may take some time for your homepage to get indexed by Google. There's no knowing just how long Google will take before indexing a page it has discovered. You may have to play the waiting game. But if you do the aforementioned things it's more likely that it will come back sooner.

Comment: Yeap, I'll do that. Lucky me that I still have the "old" domain. Nice hint, ty!

Comment: For someone with the same problem. I removed the "forbidden" on the example2.com's search console and my example1.com immediatly return to the search results.

Comment: Glad I could help. You definitely want Google to crawl the 301 from example2 to example1 and ya the effect should be pretty immediate

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have [duplicate content](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66359?hl=en) at some point. Next time, prevent `example2.com` from being indexed while you are working on it.

Once you want to disable `example2.com`, the best way to handle this is by generating a `301` redirect (one by one as long as it is possible) to `example1.com`.

If you didn't do it, now is the time.

Try to do a `site:example1.com` and check if the home is shown in the results

If it appears there, you just need to wait till Google decides to show your home in results. Check internal and external links to accelerate the process.